Read from BLE device required PIN code from windows machine using Python
I need to read data from BLE characteristic that requires PIN code.
Before PIN code feature was implemented I could read the data easily using Bleak library:
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

async def read_single_characteristic(device_address, characteristic_uuid):
    async def read_characteristic():
        try:
            async with BleakClient(device_address, timeout=35.0) as client:
                if client.address == device_address:
                    services = client.services
                    for service in services:
                        for char in service.characteristics:
                            if char.uuid == characteristic_uuid:
                                # Read the characteristic
                                data = bytes(await client.read_gatt_char(characteristic_uuid))
...

Next comes data handling
Now in order to read the data I need to enter a PIN code. The question is, is there a way to do pairing using a PIN code in Python automatically as part of reading process?

No, there is no "automatic" pairing for BLE on Windows. You have to call Pair() manually before reading data. Note, that some GATT enabled devices may need to pair before connect. Some - after. Also for secure GATT conection you may need to specify correct GATT protection level.

Do you mean that I need to write the Pair() myself or is there a ready-made one in the library?

I do not know if the lib you use provides such method. Bluetooth Framework (can be used with Python) does support BLE pairing. You can find some demos by this link: https://github.com/btframework?tab=repositories
